# mkdir: cannot create directory '/run/user/1000': Permission denied Yocto useradd

Tags: linux, yocto, openembedded, wayland

I created a custom image using the openembedded/yocto project in which I created a custom user using the below contents in the bb file.

```
inherit useradd

USERADD_PACKAGES = "${PN}"
USERADD_PARAM_${PN} = "-u 1000 \
                       -d /home/user1 \
                       -m -s /bin/bash \
                       -G adm,dialout,sudo,audio,video,plugdev,users,input \
                       -P 'user1' \
                       user1;"
```

When I ssh with that user I get the following error:
mkdir: cannot create directory '/run/user/1000': Permission denied
chmod: cannot access '/run/user/1000': No such file or directory

In addtion I am using Xwayland with the following packages in my image: weston, weston-init, weston-xwayland. The GUI starts up with the root user. Not sure if that is an issue.

Comment: what's the output of `ls -lah /run/user/1000`

Comment: ls: cannot access '/run/user/1000': No such file or directory